# How do I get the users home directory in a sandboxed app?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, appstore-sandbox

`NSHomeDirectory()` is returning my sandbox root, not my home directory. `[@"~" stringByExpandingTildeInPath]` is doing the same thing.

This `/Users/username/Library/Containers/appID/Data` is what's being returned. How do I get `/Users/username/`?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you want the path to the user's real home directory you can use:

```
char *realHome = getpwuid(getuid())->pw_dir;
```

Full example:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <assert.h>

NSString *RealHomeDirectory() {
    struct passwd *pw = getpwuid(getuid());
    assert(pw);
    return [NSString stringWithUTF8String:pw->pw_dir];
}
```

This gives you the *path* to the user's home, but does not automatically give you *access* to that folder. As noted in comments, you can use this path for:

- providing a sane default folder for the open/save dialogs
- detecting whether you are in a sandbox, by comparing the result to `NSHomeDirectory()`

Comment: The only thing its really good for is setting a sane default to the file open/save dialogs. Right now, if I set it to NSHomeDirectory() its not very user friendly. Most people don't even know what the Library folder is.

Comment: That's one good use, another is to test whether you're in the sandbox by comparing it to what `NSHomeDirectory()` returns, and I'm sure there are others...

Comment: And yet another is to gain access to a file via the `com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.home-relative-path.*` temporary entitlements

Comment: I really needed that, thanks. The powerbox nsopenpanel in our app gets used to pick locations for a few different usages, we want to warm that up to a good starting point for the user.  The wholescale change in meaning to  all the app path commands is a travesty.

Comment: As NSUserName() should always return the right value. Wouldn't it work just fine? NSString *realHomeDir = [NSString stringWithFormat@"/Users/%@",NSUserName()];

Comment: @Tibidabo - Your suggestion will work approximately 99.99% of the time. However a users home directory need not be in `/Users` and that is why it is recommended a method is used which returns the users home directory as it will be always be correct, even for the rare 0.01% cases when it is somewhere else. (And the same applies for other standard directories for which Apple provides routines to determine their path - use the routines if they are available.) HTH

Comment: @CRD Thank you for the clarification. Actually I use this approach in one of my apps and one user complained that he couldn't use the app. It seems to be 100% I have to use your approach

Answer (score 12):

From apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/DesigningYourSandbox/DesigningYourSandbox.html):

> **Accessing User Data**
>
> Mac OS X path-finding APIs, above the POSIX layer, return paths
>   relative to the container instead of relative to the user’s home
>   directory. If your app, before you sandbox it, accesses locations in
>   the user’s actual home directory (~) and you are using Cocoa or Core
>   Foundation APIs, then, after you enable sandboxing, your path-finding
>   code automatically uses your app’s container instead.
>
> For first launch of your sandboxed app, Mac OS X automatically
>   migrates your app’s main preferences file. If your app uses additional
>   support files, perform a one-time migration of those files to the
>   container, as described in “Migrating an App to a Sandbox.”
>
> **If you are using a POSIX command such as getpwuid to obtain the path
>   to the user’s actual home directory, consider instead using a Cocoa or
>   Core Foundation symbol such as the NSHomeDirectory function.** By using
>   Cocoa or Core Foundation, you support the App Sandbox restriction
>   against directly accessing the user’s home directory.
>
> **If your app requires access to the user’s home directory in order to
>   function, let Apple know about your needs using the [Apple bug
>   reporting system](https://bugreport.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/RadarWeb.woa/wa/signIn).**

Answer (score 7):

Using Swift, you can access the users home directory path from a sandboxed app like this:

```
var userHomeDirectoryPath : String {
    let pw = getpwuid(getuid())
    let home = pw?.pointee.pw_dir
    let homePath = FileManager.default.string(withFileSystemRepresentation: home!, length: Int(strlen(home)))

    return homePath
}
```

I created this solution based on a snippet in this blog post: http://zpasternack.org/accessing-the-real-home-folder-from-a-sandboxed-app/