# Preventing User From Using Desktop, Documents, Download, Movies, Music, Pictures, Public Folders

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsfilemanager

I have an **NSView** drop box, which allows the user to drag and drop a folder.  I don't want them to drag and drop the very folders like ~ Movies, ~ Music, ~ Desktop... inside User's folder.  If I run the following code, what I get is a movies folder assigned to my sandboxed application.  That's not what I want.

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] init];
url = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory: NSMoviesDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
NSLog(@"%@",[url path]);
```

I can get the right folder with 'url' above by repeating **stringByDeletingLastPathComponent** several times.  But is there a simpler way of getting that folder?  And is there a way of preventing the user from using those folders right inside the local user folder altogether?

Mucho thankos

Comment: You're talking a lot about the things you *don't* want the user to do, but what is the desired outcome here? Specifically.

Comment: Suppose that I have an application that allows the user to delete files and folders.  The application should not delete those folders.  Files inside those folder might be acceptable.  In a case like that, I need to list some paths that need to be rejected.

Answer (score 2):

The [answer to *How do I get the users home directory in objective-c in a sandboxed app?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9553390/how-do-i-get-the-users-home-directory-in-objective-c-in-a-sandboxed-app/9553507#9553507) shows you how to determine the path to the user's home directory. Once you have that you can use it in determining if a dropped folder is an immediate child of the home folder and reject it.

HTH