# how to get /Users/username/Downloads path in a sandboxed app?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, appstore-sandbox

what I've done is setup the `com.apple.security.files.downloads.read-write` to `true`, and have looked up the Apple Sandbox related docs, but I can't figure out how to get the downloads folder path, what I get is still container path like this: `/Users/username/Library/Containers/com.errpro.Snell/Data/Downloads`
, the method I use is `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains`. I've seen someone use `getpwent` to get the path, but seems not appropriate. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you are having issues with some code you wrote, then update your question with the code and point out what issues you having.

Comment: Why do you find `getpwent` (or `getpwuid`) inappropriate? It is a [valid route](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9553390/how-do-i-get-the-users-home-directory-in-objective-c-in-a-sandboxed-app) to a solution.

Comment: @CRD, that's true, it's a valid solution to retrieve the user's home dir. but how to get the downloads dir? what if the user's home is not in a regular path, and downloads dir not named 'Downloads'?

Comment: If you're thinking about language issues in regard to the naming there is an API to handle that. However the `URLForDirectory` is a better solution in this case. Was just curious at your "seems not appropriate" without any further explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the method URLForDirectory. This method find the name of the current user and insert it in the URL path.

```
NSFileManager       *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSURL               *downloadsURL;  

downloadsURL = [fm URLForDirectory:NSDownloadsDirectory
                   inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil
                   create:YES error:nil];
```

Comment: sorry, you answer seems still not work in the sandboxed env, cause the result is file:///Users/username/Library/Containers/com.errpro.prodname/Data/Downloads/, but `/Users/username/Downloads` is what I need.

Comment: /Users/username/Library/Containers/com.errpro.prodname/Data/Downloads is an alias that points to /Users/username/Downloads. It is transparent for your application

Comment: I tried it again, and you're right. The downloads dir is a symbol link to the current user's downloads dir. And is this the effect of the 'com.apple.security.files.downloads.read-write' config?

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 5**

```
do {
     let url = try FileManager.default.url(for: FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.downloadsDirectory, in: FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
} catch{
      print(error)
}
```