# Substitute user path with tilde in URL

Tags: swift, cocoa

Assume a file `URL` containing `/Users/me/a/b`. Is there a better method than a naive string replace using `NSHomeDirectory()` to get the short form `~/a/b`?

This is what I'm currently using

```
.replacingOccurrences(of: NSHomeDirectory(), with: "~", options: .anchored, range: nil)
```

PS: No `NSString` casting!

Comment: What happens if the directory has `/Users/Username/Users/Username`?... you'll end up with `~~`

Comment: Nope. Only first occurrence is replaced.

Comment: That likely depends on whether you mean iOS or macOS... it definitely replaces both on the latter.

Comment: Just tested it in a `macOS` playground and it doesnt

Comment: Strange... it replaced both for me. http://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/raw/6e36907e3f274b4aeb2b18a16a2627ca

Comment: There is definitely something wrong with your playground. Even if it would replace both occurrences, the last `/foobar` path is still missing in your example.

Comment: The last foobar shows... i screen capped before going to another line. http://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/raw/697aa6dbe9d89c40b888084c61e47927

Answer (score 3):

If you are in Sandboxed app then usage of `getpwuid` function is needed.

```
extension FileManager {
   /// Returns path to real home directory in Sandboxed application
   public var realHomeDirectory: String? {
      if let home = getpwuid(getuid()).pointee.pw_dir {
         return string(withFileSystemRepresentation: home, length: Int(strlen(home)))
      }
      return nil
   }
}
```

Example usage:

```
func configure(url: URL) {
  ...
  var directory = url.path.deletingLastPathComponent
  toolTip = url.path
  if let homeDir = FileManager.default.realHomeDirectory {
     // FYI: `url.path.abbreviatingWithTildeInPath` not working for sandboxed apps.
     let abbreviatedPath = url.path.replacingFirstOccurrence(of: homeDir, with: "~")
     directory = abbreviatedPath.deletingLastPathComponent
     toolTip = abbreviatedPath
  }
  directoryLabel.text = directory
}
```

More about `getpwuid` function: [How do I get the users home directory in a sandboxed app?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9553390/1418981)

---

Result of usage in `NSView`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How about converting to NSString and then abbreviating it with:

```
var path = url.path as NSString!
var abbrevPath=path?.abbreviatingWithTildeInPath
```

Comment: I'd rather avoid ObjC classes

Answer (score 0):

NSPathUtilities
    - (NSString *)stringByAbbreviatingWithTildeInPath;
    - (NSString *)stringByExpandingTildeInPath;

```
[blueprintsDict writeToFile: [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"~/MbPatchBlueprints.plist"] stringByExpandingTildeInPath] atomically:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this question doesn't have an accepted answer yet, and I ran into the same issue. I tried the `NSString` methods, but those didn't work in a sandboxed context anyway, and the `getpwuid` method felt… wrong. So here's a pure Swift solution that's only really hardcoded insofar as it assumes the sandbox root to share the first 3 path components (`/`, `Users`, your username) with your actual home directory:

```swift
extension URL {
    var pathAbbreviatingWithTilde: String {
        // find home directory path (more difficulty because we're sandboxed, so it's somewhere deep in our actual home dir)
        let sandboxedHomeDir = FileManager.default.homeDirectoryForCurrentUser
        let components = sandboxedHomeDir.pathComponents
        guard components.first == "/" else { return path }
        let homeDir = "/" + components.dropFirst().prefix(2).joined(separator: "/")
        
        // replace home dir in path with tilde for brevity and aesthetics
        guard path.hasPrefix(homeDir) else { return path }
        return "~" + path.dropFirst(homeDir.count)
    }
}
```