# How can I tell if a URL points to a special system folder such as Documents or Desktop in a sandboxed app?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsurl, nsfilemanager, appstore-sandbox

I have a sandboxed Cocoa app that allows the user to open and manipulate directories.

I'd like to disallow deleting special system folders such as the user's Documents and Desktop folders.

How can I tell if a file URL points to a special, protected system folder as defined in [FileManager.SearchPathDirectory](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/searchpathdirectory)?

I use `NSOpenPanel` to open a folder. For the desktop folder, I get:

```
/Users/bob/Desktop
```

Now, `FileManager` has the handy method `url(for:in:appropriateFor:create:)` for locating special directories. For example:

```
FileManager.default.url(for: .desktopDirectory, 
                        in : .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
```

returns:

```
/Users/bob/Library/Containers/com.mycompany.app/Data/Desktop
```

... which is expected, as this is a sandboxed app. But the problem now is that comparing these two urls fails, although semantically, they represent the same folder. How can I tell that they indeed point to the same folder?

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the sandbox URL to a user-relative special folder and the non-sandbox one is always `Library/Containers/<bundle id>/Data`.

For your purposes both the sandbox and non-sandbox paths should presumably both be protected from deletion, indeed anything in `~/Library/Containers` maybe should be protected.

So if `FileManager.default.url` returns a URL with a path of the form `/Users/<name>/Library/Container/<bundle id>/Data/<folder...>` you can use `NSRegularExpression` to match against this and map it to `/User/<name>/<folder...>`. Writing the RE is left as an exercise!

HTH

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but the problem is the other way around: I receive the URL `/Users/bob/Desktop` from the Powerbox via NSOpenPanel and have to decide if *this* is a protected system location. I know that all results to `FileManager.default.url(for:in:appropriateFor:create:)` are protected system locations (by design). My problem is that I can't match those against the user-provided location.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding something here about your problem but surely it doesn't matter which URL you get from which source as you can map them to each other in either direction by inserting or removing `Library/Containers/<bundle id>/Data/`.

Comment: My concern is that the pattern `Library/Containers/<bundle id>/Data/` is an implementation detail. The location could change, breaking the mapping. My question is, if there is an official API to tell if a user-provided path is the Desktop folder, for example.

Comment: OK, read this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9553390/how-do-i-get-the-users-home-directory-in-a-sandboxed-app/9553507#9553507) and you'll find out how to get a users real home directory - using `getpwuid()` - and the sandboxed app's effective home directory - using [`NSHomeDirectory()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1413045-nshomedirectory?language=objc). The difference between these two is the string you are concerned may change, and if the real home is not a prefix of the sandbox home you know there has a major system change. Does that help?